# What's wrong with this recursive function?

Tags: php, recursion

Here's my recursive function:

```
function get_descendants($category_id)
{
    global $descendants;

    $categories = get_ancestors($category_id);
echo "get_ancestors($category_id);<br>";

//  print_r($categories);exit;

    if (!is_array($categories))
        return;

    foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
        $descendants[] = $category['id'];

        // Look for other leafs
        get_descendants($category['id']);
    }

    return $descendants;
}

function get_ancestors($parent_id)
{
    global $db, $locale;

    $result = $db->query("
            SELECT ...
                AND parent_id = $parent_id
    ");

    $categories = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        foreach ($categories as $category)
            $data[] = $category;

        return $data;
    }
}
```

The problem it's making the same call twice. So this is the result of running the code:

```
get_ancestors(8);
get_ancestors(1);
get_ancestors(2);
get_ancestors(4);
get_ancestors(5);
get_ancestors(3);
get_ancestors(6);
get_ancestors(8);
get_ancestors(1);
get_ancestors(2);
get_ancestors(4);
get_ancestors(5);
get_ancestors(3);
get_ancestors(6);
```

Where I should only see:

```
get_ancestors(8);
get_ancestors(1);
get_ancestors(2);
get_ancestors(4);
get_ancestors(5);
get_ancestors(3);
get_ancestors(6);
```

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably should not declare your $descendants variable as global, otherwise it is never "cleared".

Comment: Your `get_ancestors()` method seems to return descendents instead of ancestors, shouldn't your `get_ancestors()` method have an other name, like `get_childs()` ?

Comment: That's correct. I'm intending to rename the function soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you **don't** want `$descendants` to be `global`.

You are sharing one variable across all the recursive calls. It really needs to be local for the logic you're using to be correct.

Instead of `global $descendants;` do `$descendants = array();`.